# Trouble checking if a text field contains specific text

Tags: javascript, if-statement, netbeans

How do I check if a text field has a certain text entered into it when a button is pushed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the value of text input field using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-text-input-field-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

This bit of code will search the string 'searchMe' for the string 'lookFor' and store the result (boolean) inside of 'result'

```
  let searchMe = 'can you find me in here?'; //string to search
  let lookFor = new RegExp("find me"); //reg exp pattern to look for 
  let result = lookFor.test(searchMe); //result of the search (true/false)
```

Try and apply this logic to your button click handler. Good luck!